# Main nav items sharing child pages in Liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay, portal, liferay-6, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

FYI, I'm new to Liferay so please have patience with me!

Here's the scenario:
I have a main `nav` menu working in my `navigation.vm`. I've determined that two of the main nav items would share the same child menu listing the same pages.

I've gone into the GUI and created the child pages but must I create the same set of pages twice for both `nav` items which share the child pages or is there some method by which I can create these child pages once and then share them between the pages and just bring in different data?

So to restate:
Can I have two `nav` items share one sub-menu with the same child pages and just bring in unique data to each of the child pages based on the main `nav` item selected?

If this isn't clear, let me know and I will try to explain better.

Comment: You must create seperate set of children pages for each parent with the same name if you want to. and put unique data(portlets) on the children pages created.

There is an option to copy the contents one page to another page.

Comment: Thanks Sharana ... it appears Prakash K is suggesting the same solution.  I'm waiting to confirm this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Here is what I understand:***

- You have created two pages - `Page-1` and `Page-2`.
- You need child-pages to be shared for these pages, like:

  ```
   Page-1    Page-2
    __|__      __|__
   |     |    |     |
   cp1  cp2  cp1   cp2
  ```
- Where `cp1` & `cp2` are child-pages 1 & 2.
- Based on which child-pages the portlets are added, they should show different data.

***Here is my take on this:***

Since content on the set of child-pages is different, I would suggest creating two set of child-pages with the same name i.e. to say `cp1` of `Page-1` is not equal to `cp1` of `Page-2`.

This would let you simplify management and also if you decide later that the `layout` of the child-pages should be completely different from each-other or to have completely different set of portlets then it would be easier since anyways they would be different pages instead of being shared.

Hope I have answered your question and it would help.

Comment: Thanks Prakash K ... if I understand your response correctly, you suggest that I create (in the GUI) the same child pages for Page-1 and Page-2, essentially creating these child pages twice.  I would then differentiate the data in each page by creating unique portlets for the same.  Did I get that right?